# Compute mean and variance waiting time of M/M/1 Queue

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Jobs arrive at a machine following a Poisson process with rate λ. The machine processes
jobs one at a time, and the processing times follow i.i.d. exponential distribution with mean 1/µ,
independent of the arrival process. Suppose at t = 0, the machine is occupied, processing a job.
Let Y be the number of jobs waiting in queue when the machine completes processing that job.
Derive the mean and variance of Y.

Comment: Not sure how to start this problem..

Comment: Do you know how to find $P(Y=k)$ if you know the machine finishes the job at time $t$ for sure? Extend this method by writing $P(Y=k)$ in terms of conditional probability

Comment: Only thing I gathered is the machine can process jobs only if $\lambda < \mu$ otherwise the queue keeps filling up. So I'm guessing at time t, Machine finishes the job if $\lambda < \mu$. What do I do next?

Comment: You can write $Y=X+Z$ where $X$ is the random number of jobs in queue at time $0$, and $Z$ is the (independent) number of more jobs that arrive while the residual service time completes.  I think you are supposed to assume that $X$ has a distribution derived by taking the steady state distribution adn conditioning on teh system being nonempty.

Comment: The answer according to the professor is $\lambda/\mu$ for E(Y) and $\lambda/\mu +(\lambda/\mu)^2$ for Var(Y)

Comment: You should have posted under the [queueing-theory] tag. It would have gathered more answers there...

Comment: are you sure that its a "+" and not a "-" in the variance term?